# LDO without ground

Tags: ldo

I am trying to simplify the schematics and work around chip shortage at the same time. In current implementation the MCU is talking to BMS via [ISOW7821](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/isow7821) isolator. The primary reason for this was to isolate the ground, not the Tx/Rx lines. The PCB with MCU receives power over heavy gauge wires. However if the ground wire gets disconnected for any reason, up to 80A may try to go over 28AWG ground in BMS connection.

Now, since the board does have +24V from the battery, I've decided to replace that isolator with simple LDO ([MCP1799T](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP1799-Data-Sheet-20006248A.pdf)) and cheap digital isolator ([SI8422AB](https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/Skyworks/SL/documents/public/data-sheets/si841x-2x-datasheet.pdf)) combination. What I am worried about, is the plugging/unplugging of the BMS. If the UART pins got connected before the ground pin, then it seems to me there could be full battery voltage coming through LDO on those wires (INA, OUTB), relative to the BMS ground or internal BMS 3.3V power rail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fggVgu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

UPDATE:

Just to clarify, the question is - **How does LDO behave with floating ground pin?** Is it a) open circuit, b) closed circuit, or c) something in between, depending on internal schematics and/or load impedance?

From the discussion with @DKNguyen it seems to be c), and the suggested protection is resistors/zeners on Tx/Rx pins. Zeners will not work, however, without the ground. But I certainly can put in some series resistors.

Regarding schematics, the connectors can be plugged/unplugged in any order. Furthermore, they do not guarantee any specific order of their pins making contact. So, there can be any combination of those five wires, if only for a short time.

Comment: "*If the UART pins got connected before the ground pin, then it seems to me there could be full battery voltage coming through LDO on those wires (INA, OUTB), relative to the BMS ground.*" I don't understand what you mean. Care to elaborate what how you think the BMS functions?

Comment: @DKNguyen I have very vague idea how BMS functions. But I know how people function - they like to plug/unplug things. Unless the connector has some special "connect first" pins, there is no guarantee that the ground will be connected first. If that is the case, INA pin will be connected by its pullup to 24V output from LDO, and I don't think BMS serial port will be happy about it. Note that all these are just guesses. I don't really know how LDO behaves with floating ground, hence the title of this question.

Comment: I don't see why the BMS would end up applying 24V to INA or OUTB if the BMS ground is disconnected, because the 24V it can apply is with respect to its ground. If that ground is disconnected, then the BMS can't force 24V across anything. Instead, the 24V pin floats up to the potential of whatever you connected it to while the disconnected BMS ground ends up being 24V below that.

Comment: Just to clarify - I want to make sure that regardless of the order the two connectors plugged/unplugged, and regardless of the order the pins in those connectors make contact, nothing will burn out. Furthermore, bad contact on either one of those high-current power wires should not damage the electronics either, which was the reason for using isolator chip there in the first place

Comment: It's like if I have a 2 story building and a 3 story building sitting at sea level on earth. if I try to connect the top floors with a pedway, there is going to be a problem since the top floors are not in alignment since the bottom floors are being anchored to the same alignment by the Earth. But if they were floating in space, no problem since the pedway would just force both buildings to float into position such that their top floors were aligned to each other.

Comment: However, if I then try to connect their bottom floors with another pedway, that will similarly cause a problem again because the first pedway is holding both top floors in alignment, just like the Earth was doing to the bottom floors previously. If you still have concerns of some kind, you can just place 10K resistors in series with INA and OUTB.

Comment: @DKNguyen I did not mean that BMS would apply voltage to U2 pins, rather the other way around. My theory is that if ground wire (the one that goes to GND1 on the schematics) is not connected, then the LDO cannot regulate, and it will output 24V to VDD1. This maybe harmless by itself, since GND1 is floating, but if INA/OUTB pins are connected to UART port on BMS, the port components inside BMS are _not_ floating. Can this situation create harmful current flow BAT+ -> LDO:IN -> LDO:OUT -> U2:VDD1 -> U2:INA -> BMS:TX -> BAT-, for example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140202/discussion-between-dknguyen-and-maple).